# QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt 4.6.0 (32 bit) under Windows 7 Ultimate. Consider the following `QThread`:

### Interface

```
class ResultThread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

    QString _post_data;
    QNetworkAccessManager _net_acc_mgr;

signals:
    void onFinished(QNetworkReply* net_reply);

private slots:
    void onReplyFinished(QNetworkReply* net_reply);

public:
    ResultThread();

    void run();
    void setPostData(const QString& post_data);
};
```

### Implementation

```
ResultThread::ResultThread() : _net_acc_mgr(this)
{
    connect(&_net_acc_mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(onReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void ResultThread::onReplyFinished(QNetworkReply* net_reply)
{
    emit onFinished(net_reply);
}

void ResultThread::setPostData(const QString& post_data)
{
    _post_data = post_data;
}

void ResultThread::run()
{
    _net_acc_mgr.post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://[omitted]")),
                      QByteArray(_post_data.toStdString().c_str()));
}
```

Whenever `_net_acc_mgr.post()` is executed in `ResultThread::run()`, I got the following Application Output in Qt Creator:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
>
> (Parent is QNetworkAccessManager(0x22fe58), parent's thread is QThread(0x9284190), current thread is ResultThread(0x22fe48)

What does this mean? How to solve it?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The **run()** member function is executed in a different thread, rather than the thread where `QNetworkRequestManager` object was created.

This kind of different-thread problems happen all the time with **Qt** when you use multiple threads. The canonical way to solve this problem is to use *signals* and *slots*.

Create a *slot* in the object where `QNetworkRequestManager` belongs to, create a *signal* in **ResultThread** and connect both of the somewhere, the constructor of **ResultThread** would be a good place.

The code which is currently in **ResultThread::run()** goes to the new *slot*, and is replaced by a `emit(yourSignal())`. If necessary send a pointer to your **ResultThread** as a parameter with your emit function to gain access to member functions/variables.

Comment: This works but looks weird to me. I declared _net_acc_mgr inside `ResultThread` but `ResultThread::run()` executes in another thread! Why Qt is designed in this way? Particularly, why `ResultThread::run()` runs in another thread rather than `ResultThread`?

Comment: Welcome to the world of multithreading. Actually, the thread in which ResultThread is created is always different to the one, where ResultThread::run() is executed. Think about it, it doesn't make sense any other way.
The whole purpose of QThread is to run something in a different thread. To do this, you need to set up the data for the new thread somewhere and this happens in the thread where you create ResultThread. When this is done, you are able to run the thread - of course it runs then in a different thread...

Comment: Then, if all code is moved to the slot, the slot will execute in the parent thread. Why we create the child thread?

Comment: You might misunderstand how QThread is intedend to be used. In your case it might be better to not implement the run method but instead move a worker QObject (which has to be different from the QThread object) to the QThread. 
Take a look at the examples in the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details

Comment: Why do you say "Create a slot in the object where QNetworkRequestManager belongs to" when you could just say "Create a slot in the object in ResultThread"? It is obvious (at least to me) that QNetworkRequestManager object belongs to ResultThread.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error message when I forgot to set the QNetworkRequestManager's parent.

```
nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
```