# QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtwebkit

Greeting

I have a following class.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant status();

public:
    MyClass(ClassX * classX);

public slots:
    void slotA();
    void slotB();

signals:
    void signalA();
    void signalB();

private:
    void init();
    void doSomething();

private:
    ClassX * classX;
    ClassA classA;
    ClassB classB;
};
```

In `MyClass`'s constructor, I set `classX` to `this.classX` and in `init()`, I `connect` some of `classX` signals to `MyClass` slots and wise-versa and in `someFunction()` i use `classA` and `classB`.

In my `controller` class in main thread, I create `MyClass` object and run it inside different thread.

```
MyClass * myClass = new MyClass(classX);
connect(&myClassThread, SIGNAL(started()), myClass, SLOT(init()));
myClass->moveToThread(&myClassThread);
myClassThread.start();
```

I see the following warning in `qDebugger`.

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

Can anyone tell me why i get that warning ?

Thanks in advanced

PS 1: The `classX` created in main thread.

PS 2 : Remember, Everything work fine and i don't have any problem, I just want to know the reason of this warning and how to fix it.

PS 3 : I also use the following command in main thread to expose the object in `javascript`.

```
webFrame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myClassObject", myClass);
```

Edit 1 : QThread myClassThread is class member.

Edit 2 : I believe the lack of information, confused you guys and i'm sorry about that.

The constructor of `MyClass` is like this :

```
MyClass::MyClass(ClassX * classX)
{
     this.classX = classX;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268073/qobject-cannot-create-children-for-a-parent-that-is-in-a-different-thread)

Comment: easily the nth question about this. `MyClass * myClass = new MyClass(classX);` should be `MyClass * myClass = new MyClass(0);`. Full stop.

Comment: @UmNyobe Even with no parameters i still get the warnings

Comment: @UmNyobe This is not duplicate question, As you can see, I called the methods of myClass via signal-slot! Even if i don't call any methods, or don't even use the object after creation, I still get the warning

Comment: I didnt mention signal and slot. If the code snippet above doesnt work with new Myclass(0), then it is different from your real code (as the one above is just for the problem statement).

Comment: @UmNyobe with MyClass(0) i still get the warning but as i mentioned, The code run and i have no problem, Just want to find the warning reason

Comment: show constructor of MyClass. do you pass a QObject as first parameter of the constructor without it being used as a parent? In this case you are confusing us.

Comment: @UmNyobe Please check Edit 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's be clear. **Your code is not working as you intended it to work.** That is what the framework is telling you.

> QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different
>   thread

This means all slots and signals of a certain object (suspected `myClass`) will not be executed in the same thread as the one expected. The issue here revolves around the parent of either `myClass` or `classX` objects

**Possibility I : myClass->moveToThread(&myClassThread); is failing**

***Cause:*** myClass has a parent already set. which is forbidden.

It means that `init()` will be triggered by the thread of the thread object `myClassThread`. Thread-wise and event-wise, this is almost the same as if you did

```
MyClass * myClass = new MyClass(classX);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myClass, "init", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

**Possibility II : init() is violating thread affinity**

***Cause:*** `classX``or a mysterious related object has a parent already set or is not movable to another thread. Think widget.

`moveToThread` succeed, you have `MyClass` in one thread, and `classX` in another thread. You have provided `classX` when constructing `myClass`. `myClass` is now manipulating an object in another thread, and without further code we cannot assume thread safety or correct child parent affinity. Review `MyClass`::MyClass` and MyClass::init carefully.

**Which One is Occurring?**

Try putting a break in the debugger, in the controller code and look at the thread id. Then put a break in the debugger in the `init` method.

- If it is the same thread, case I
- Otherwise it is case II

Comment: Thanks alot for youre answer, i got it

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in many ways:

```
QThread myClassThread;
MyClass * myClass = new MyClass(classX);
connect(&myClassThread, SIGNAL(started()), myClass, SLOT(init()));
myClass->moveToThread(&myClassThread);
myClassThread.start();
```

1. You are creating thread object on stack not on heap! This means `myClassThread` object will be destroyed when this block of code ends.
2. `myClass` has a parent. Object which are moved to thread can't have any parent. Only whole three of objects can be moved to threads

Comment: About 1 : I just added Edit 1, myClassThread is class member actually. About 2 : myClass's parent is QObject. I don't think that causing it

Comment: you’re moving myClass to another thread, but classX stays in the main thread. Thus the warning. Don’t use classX as parent for myClass if you want to move myClass to another thread.