# Fix QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5

I have noticed this message in my Application Output in Qt Creator:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QUdpSocket(0x557d126bb830), parent's thread is QThread(0x557d11d1d680), current thread is QThread(0x557d126c64d0)
```

I use:

- GCC 13.2.1 as a compiler.
- Qt 5.15.11.
- Qt Creator 11.0.3.

My project is a little larger, so I am providing [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It contains class **UDPClient** for sending UDP packets and class **MyProcessing** that is for preparing UDP packets.

*main.cpp*:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow w;
    w.show();

    UDPClient c(&w, QHostAddress("192.168.1.255"), 5001);
    MyProcessing p(NULL, "Hi!");

    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1000);
    timer.setTimerType(Qt::TimerType::PreciseTimer);

    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &p, SLOT(onTimeout()));
    QObject::connect(&p, SIGNAL(sigNewDataReady(QByteArray)),
                     &c, SLOT(onNewUDPDataReceived(QByteArray)),
                     Qt::DirectConnection);

    p.start();
    timer.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

*udpclient.h*:

```
#ifndef UDPCLIENT_H
#define UDPCLIENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QUdpSocket>

class UDPClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UDPClient(QObject *parent = nullptr,
                       QHostAddress aAddr = QHostAddress("192.168.0.20"),
                       quint16 aPortNum = 0);
public slots:
    void onNewUDPDataReceived(QByteArray data);

private:
    QUdpSocket  *udpSocket;
    quint16      portNum;
    QHostAddress addr;
};

#endif // UDPCLIENT_H
```

*udpclient.cpp*:

```
#include "udpclient.h"

UDPClient::UDPClient(QObject *parent, QHostAddress aAddr, quint16 aPortNum)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    portNum = aPortNum;
    addr    = aAddr;
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket();
}

void UDPClient::onNewUDPDataReceived(QByteArray data)
{
    udpSocket->writeDatagram(data, addr, portNum);
}
```

*myprocessing.h*:

```
#ifndef MYPROCESSING_H
#define MYPROCESSING_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class MyProcessing : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyProcessing(QObject *parent = nullptr, QByteArray text = "text");

    void start() { mThread->start(); }

signals:
    void sigNewDataReady(QByteArray);

public slots:
    void onTimeout() {emit sigNewDataReady(QByteArray(mText)); }

private:
    QByteArray mText;
    QThread *mThread;
};

#endif // MYPROCESSING_H
```

*myprocessing.cpp*:

```
#include "myprocessing.h"

MyProcessing::MyProcessing(QObject *parent, QByteArray text)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    mText = text;
    mThread = new QThread;
    this->moveToThread(mThread);
}
```

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268073/qobject-cannot-create-children-for-a-parent-that-is-in-a-different-thread) on similar Application Output suggest to not inherit from QThread class, and suggest using similar way as I did here.

Comment: Change to `new QUdpSocket(this)`

Comment: I tried... Same result

Comment: `onUDPServerThreadStarted` is running in main thread, is that your intention?

Comment: My intention was to use this slot (`onUDPServerThreadStarted`) as an initialization when I start `udpThread`, but I want it to be in `udpThread`. From _main_ _thread_ I am just calling `start()` method, when I want to start `udpThread` execution. I do not understand your comment fully, I am sorry. Did you mean `onUDPServerThreadStarted` is in _main_ _thread_? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  Also note that if you wish to know on which thread your `onUDPServerThreadStarted` method is being called you can check/compare the output of [`QThread::currentThreadId`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#currentThreadId).

Comment: @G.M. Thanks to your suggestion to use `QThread::currentThreadId` I found why error occured I solved it. I am omw to edit this question so I can show error in [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @G.M suggestion to use `QThread::currentThreadId` I found error to be caused by `Qt::DirectConnection` in *main.cpp*. `Qt::DirectConnection` is causing `SLOT(onNewUDPDataReceived(QByteArray))` to be runned in `p`'s thread.
Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051553/qt-signals-queuedconnection-and-directconnection) for more explanation.

Simply removing `Qt::DirectConnection` solves the problem.